# Role of Parantheses in array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++

Trying to implement Graphs using [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) link, I came across a serious syntax doubt.

```
/ A structure to represent an adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};

// A structure to represent an adjacency liat
struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};
```

In the I mentioned above, it is implemented in C, whereas I have implemented it in C++.
And now a function to create the Data Structure of the Graph:

```
struct Graph* createGraph(int V) {
  struct Graph *graph;
  graph = new (struct Graph);
  graph->V = V;

  //the problem line below   
  graph->array = new (struct AdjList)[V];
  //initialize all the elements in the array as NULL
  for(int i = 0; i < V ; i++) {
    graph->array[i].head = NULL;
  }
  return graph;
}
```

This code gives the error :array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id
Whereas if I just remove the paranthese from the problem line, everything works fine. 
Why is this happening?

EDIT:

I know how to fix the problem. Just need to do this.

```
graph->array = new struct AdjList[V];
```

**The question is WHY is it incorrect?**

Comment: Just remove the parenthesis and the `struct`s. No point for either to be there.

Comment: I understand that struct is not required. But that does not make it wrong. I want to know WHY using the parenthese is incorrect here. I am not sure if struct has anything to do with it. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Just do `graph->array = new struct AdjList[V];`. By the way, `struct Graph` is a relatively small object, so you may as well allocate it on the stack and return it by value.

Comment: The `[V]` forms part of the type.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please elaborate. I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common [`new` expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) variants that allows parenthesis between the keyword and the type. The entities enclosed within go in as arguments to the `operator new` function. They're useful

1. To specify the memory manually instead of using the default `operator new` function.
2. To specify a no-throw behaviour. This is handy when you don't want the new expression to throw a `std::bad_alloc` when freestore allocation fails.

**1. placement new**

```
char* ptr = new char[sizeof(T)];   // allocate memory
T* tptr = new(ptr) T;              // construct in allocated storage ("place")
tptr->~T();                        // destruct
```

**2. nothrow**

```
auto p* = new (std::nothrow) char;
```

This will not throw but would set `p` to `nullptr` if the allocation fails.

> The question is WHY is it incorrect?

Because it isn't part of the allowed grammar where the parenthesis can occur; the error `array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id` means the compiler thinks you did this

```
T *arr = new (T) [count];
```

which is invalid since for an array, you do

```
T *arr = new T[count];
```

i.e. the type without parenthesis. Here, as mentioned in comments by juanchopanza, the type is `T[]`, so you could do `T *arr = new (T[count]);`.

Answer (score 2):

> *"**The question is WHY is it incorrect?**"*

The chapter 5.3.4 of the [c++ language specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf), pretty clearly shows that the parenthesis immeadeatly following the `new` keyword are preseved for *placement new* expressions:

[image]